# Data in custom attribute not returned in UserProfile object in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, user-profile

I've created two new custom attributes in the UserProfile.  When the service we wrote returns data about a specific user by using the UserProfile object, sometimes the data isn't returned, even though if we look at the user in SSP it look populated.  Some users work; this is the first user we set up with data.  I'm not sure if sometime in the meantime after setting up the first user and testing, if there's something we ran and need to run again.  How can I get all the users to get their data returned in a call to their UserProfile?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a language issue, perhaps you can detect a pattern in working/not working users and their language?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the visibility of the custom attributes? Is it possible that it's a question of who is supposed to be able see the attribute that is causing your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It could be connected to when the profile was created and when the attributes were added.

Is there any pattern to which users work and which do not?

Try creating a new user, and see if the attributes are available for that user.